# Constraining image's placement / size for a background in a div

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I am trying to make my background image constrained so it fills the section but is not so zoomed in. Any help would be appreciated. I currently have this code

```
    <div class="full-width-bg larger-text" style="padding-top: 50px;">
    <div class="custom-bg bgsIE bg-image" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');">
    </div>
    <div class="content-container">
    <h2><span style="color: #154774;"><strong>Sign up now for <br>a 14-day trial</strong></span></h2>
    <p><a href="" class="btn large darker-gray">Try it for free today</a>
    <hr class="gap" style="margin:50px 0 0 0;">
    </div></div>
```

This is how it looks so far:

[image]

How i want it to look
[image]

Comment: use background-size: 100% 100%; or 100% height-of-ur-section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `background-position: center;` along with the background-image property and see the result. If there’s an issue with spacing there is the background-size property which in most cases is best to set as `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Thanks, im not particularly good at coding but needs must. I have done what you said (i think correctly)  style="background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-position: center; background-size: cover;"></div>

Comment: Yeah that should work for you. Depending on the image dimensions you may have to change the background-size to 100% 100%. Just depends on how you want to handle stretching/shrinking the image

Comment: No problem, mark as the answer if it solved your issue.